# Change hostname from localhost to sth to enable google reCAPTCHA domain on mac

Tags: reactjs, localhost, gatsby

I was trying to use google reCAPTCHA on my gatsby project.

I would like to use it on my local server without inserting my localhost domain on it.
So i added site domain name on my /etc/hosts and changed local server name using

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop -H mydomain.com -p 8000",
    "format": "prettier --write src/**/*.{js,jsx}",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "test": "jest",
    "deploy": "gatsby build --prefix-paths && gh-pages -d public"
  },
```

I started the dev server using `npm start` and the local server was on.

```
You can now view xxx-xxx in the browser.
⠀
  http://your-domain.com:8000/
⠀
View GraphiQL, an in-browser IDE, to explore your site's data and schema
⠀
  http://your-domain.com:8000/___graphql
```

but when i go to http://your-domain.com:8000, it gives me error:
`This site can’t be reached`.

This is my hosts file

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##

127.0.0.1   your-domain.com
...
```

When i visit localhost:8000, it works.
I am not sure why this is still on localhost other than `your-domain.com`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any updates on this?